# Subset rows from similar factors with unequal levels

Tags: r

I am having a hard time to subset rows from a dataframe based on a specific condition.

I have a simple dataframe with 2 columns containing factors.
And I want to keep rows where factor of Column1 equals factor of Column2.

My problem is that factors of Column 1 have much more levels than factors of Column 2.
I do:

```
subset(df , df$Col1==df$Col2)
```

But it tells me factors dont have same levels. I've heard about `droplevels()` or `drop` to be used with `subset` function.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Convert these columns into character vectors using `as.character`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df<-data.frame(f1=factor(sample(1:4,100,TRUE)),
               f2=factor(sample(1:3,100,TRUE)))
subdf<-filter(df, as.character(f1)==as.character(f2))
subdf
   f1 f2
1   1  1
2   3  3
3   3  3
4   3  3
5   3  3
6   2  2
7   3  3
8   2  2
9   1  1
10  2  2
11  1  1
12  1  1
13  2  2
14  2  2
15  3  3
16  3  3
17  1  1
18  1  1
> str(subdf)
'data.frame':   18 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ f1: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 1 2 ...
 $ f2: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 1 2 ...
```